# finding the error page for 404

Tags: php, .htaccess

We are redirecting 404 error pages to a php page to track.
We had used `.htaccess` code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php?sr=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but when on our `404.php` page we are trying to fetch:

```
$requri = getenv ("REQUEST_URI");
```

It is not showing us the pagename from which user got redirected like `abc.html` and we want to detect that page name, can anyone help in this matter?

Comment: Have you tried `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` instead?

Comment: `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable is part of `rewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives. This doesnt work with `ErrorDocument`

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod-rewrite  to redirect a non-existent request to 404.php :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php?sr=$1 [NC,L]
```

**-d** matches an existing directory and **-f** matches an existing file on the server. RewriteCond checks to see that the requested filename is not **!** an existing directory or file before it redirects the request to /404.php.
You can also replace `$1` with `%{REQUEST_URI}` to get the full uri.

Comment: Good answer @starkeen